# Disk Support HP 400 SAS controller

Tags: hard-drive, hp, sas, controller

I receive a months ago an HP Proliant DL360 G5 with an HP Smart Array P400i Controller with 256 Mb, i have 2 sas 10k 72 Tb disk and i want to upgrade.
I buyed 4 HDD SAS 10K Hitachi 450 Gb, but the controller don't recognize them, the led will remain red in this units when i power on the server.
I think the firmware in the Controller is the last (7.24b version)
I read that this controller support disk until 1 Tb or more in SAS

Any Idea about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Go for HP(E)-branded hard disk drives, they are sold cheap on eBay.

Comment: The Hitachi disk I buyed have stickers of HP, Can the controller not support these models (model: HUC109045CSS600 of 450 Gb) and support others?